# How to replace search_character with replacement of the original_string in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to build this function that will replace all search_characters with replacement of orginal_string. I cannot use the replace operator. For example what I'm trying to do is to get the name "bob" to become "lol".
I have got a two codes that look like this:

code 1:

```
    def replace_char_in_string(original_string,search_character,replacement):
        empty_string = ""
        for search_character in original_string:
            if search_character == replacement:
                empty_string = empty_string + search_character
            else:
                empty_string = empty_string + replacement
         return empty_string
    print(replace_char_in_string("bob","b","l"))
```

However, this code gives me the output "lll".

code 2:

```
    def replace_char_in_string(original_string,search_character,replacement):
        empty_string = ""
        for search_character in original_string:
            if search_character != replacement:
                empty_string = empty_string + search_character
            else:
                empty_string = empty_string + replacement
        return empty_string
     print(replace_char_in_string("bob","b","l"))
```

And this code gives me the output "bob" again.

I'm not quite sure how to tackle the problem at this point.

Comment: You overwrote the passed `search_character` argument with the loop variable, and you're comparing it to `replacement`. You need to compare the passed `search_character` to each character in the `original_string`.

Comment: use .replace built in function!!  'bob'.replace('b','l')

Comment: @MaxwellRedacted He said he's not allowed to use that.

Comment: yeah he did I apologies, I thought everyone was losing their minds, glad it was only me

Comment: @MaxwellRedacted he didn't say he's not __allowed__, he __cannot__, because builtin replace replaces only first occurrence

Comment: @Barmarhe didn't say he's not allowed, he cannot, because builtin replace replaces only first occurrence

Comment: @Programmer no it doesn't

Comment: @MaxwellRedacted ok, sorry, you were right, but i do wonder why i thought string.replace only replaces the first occurrence. I once had an issue with it only replacing the first occurrence, wonder why ... Ok. but thanks for teaching me something new ! "Life is learning" ...

Comment: @Programmer, no worries, I think I have had that issue at some point also but cannot remember if it was in python or another language

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is your argument has the same name as your variable inside the function. This won't work. This code works:

```
def replace_char_in_string(original_string, search_character, replacement):
    empty_string = ""
    for character in original_string:
        if character == search_character:
            empty_string = empty_string + replacement
        else:
            empty_string = empty_string + character
    return empty_string


print(replace_char_in_string("bob", "b", "l"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def replace_char_in_string(original_string, search_character, replacement):
    empty_string = ""
    for search_character in original_string:
        if search_character == replacement:
            empty_string = empty_string + search_character
        else:
            empty_string = empty_string + replacement
    return empty_string
print(replace_char_in_string("bob", "b", "l"))
```

You are overwriting the input `search_character` with the actual letter of `original_string`. And your `if` will always be False, except if someone inputs a replacement the same as the search character ! Following code should work (untested, it's already late ...) :

```py
def replace_char_in_string(original_string, search_character, replacement):
    empty_string = ""
    for character in original_string:
        if character == replacement:
            empty_string += search_character
        else:
            empty_string += replacement
    return empty_string
print(replace_char_in_string("bob", "b", "l"))
```

But, if you just need a function to replace all occurrences of a letter in a string, you can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) :

```py
import re
print(re.sub("b", "l", "bob")) # the string which should be changed comes last, not first ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the first one I see the following things that went wrong:

```
def replace_char_in_string(original_string,search_character,replacement):
    empty_string = ""
    for search_character in original_string: # search_character is the same as your parameter
        if search_character == replacement: # if statement should be comparaing search_character with search_character parameter
            empty_string = empty_string + search_character # this should concat the replacement not search_character
        else:
            empty_string = empty_string + replacement # this should concat search_character not replacement
    return empty_string
```

Below a working version of the same code:

```
def replace_char_in_string(original_string,search_character,replacement):
    empty_string = ""
    for char in original_string:
        if char == search_character:
            empty_string += replacement
        else:
            empty_string += char
    return empty_string
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers may be more appropriate since they have fixed the fault in your code for you, however I wanted to share my solution none the less as I think it is rather clever,
I used list comprehension to replace the characters and then converted the list back to a string with .join method

```
myStr = "bob bobidy bob....b__b"

def replace_char_in_string(original_string,search_character,replacement):
  newStr = ''.join([a if a != search_character else replacement for a in original_string])
  return newStr

print(replace_char_in_string(myStr, 'b', 'l'))
```